# is there a way to find out all clojure libraries on clojars/maven that have a dependency on <x>?

Tags: clojure

I wish to find out who is using what libraries to answer questions like

- how many projects are using datomic, fs, etc...
- how many projects are using hiccup as compared to enlive...
- what kind of projects are using clojure.logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.clojuresphere.com/ which shows dependencies as well as dependent projects and has a REST API as well.